# How to cater for an object which can be both null or empty

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, oop

I've got an object, specifically the following:

`table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value`

If there is not property, the `Value` is null.  If there is a property, but it is empty, the `Value.toString()` is `""`.

I would thus like to create an if-statement which caters for both eventualities.  This is what I've done so far:

```
if (table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"] == null ||
    table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value.ToString().Equals(""))
```

The problem is that if it is null, it is still checking the condition on the right-hand-side.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it?  The `||` operator should short-circuit and not check the second condition if the first is true.

Comment: I disagree. Add debugging statements and you'll see that if `table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"] == null`, then the right side never gets called

Comment: Problem is that `table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"]` is not null, but `table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Decription"].Value` is null.

Comment: What type of object do you get from table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"] ?  Knowing this could really help you optimize your code. See my comment below about some shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thus `Value` is not a string, then you have to deal with all conditions:

```
var description = table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"];
if (description == null ||
    description.Value == null || 
    description.Value.ToString().Equals(""))
    // no value
```

*BTW* your code is not quite correct

```
if (table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"] == null ||
    table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value.ToString().Equals(""))
```

Instead of checking Value for null, you are checking if `table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"]` is not null. Thats true. You go further, but if `table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value` is null (you didn't check that, remember?), you will get NullReferenceException on applying `ToString()`.

Comment: The problem is that it's not a string

Comment: what about is nullorwhitespace

Comment: @Developer Value is not a string, thus we should call ToString first, which is not an option - we should check manually for null before :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
if (table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value))
```

The reason your code errors is because you don't check if `table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value` is null.

Comment: Then you need to check for that explicitly. See updated sample.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are referring to the `DataTable.ExtendedProperties` property or something else, but if you are, the property returns a `System.Data.PropertyCollection`, which inherits from `System.Collections.HashTable`.

Most of the methods and properties, including the indexer ("Item") being discussed here, are directly inherited from HashTable, so in general, table.ExtendedProperties[key] can return any object, including null.

Note that you can also call `DataTable.ExtendedProperties.ContainsKey(object key)` to determine if the PropertyCollection contains a specific key or not.

Do you know what type of object you are retrieving when you call `table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value` ?

If so, there might be other properties you can use to determine whether the property has been set, etc.

Depending on what type of object `table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"]` is, you might even be able to do something like this:

```
if ((table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"] ?? "").ToString().Length == 0) {
      .....
}
```

That would take into account all of the possibilities:

- the key doesn't exist
- the key exists, but the value is null
- the key exists and the value is empty

as long as the `table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Decription"]` object returns "" when its Value property is either null or empty.
So a little more information on the object that is returned could go a long way!

Answer (score 0):

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"]` is never null, you should be null checking the `Value` property instead

```
string value = table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value;
if (value == null || value.ToString().Equals(""))
// OR 
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
```

If `table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"]` can return null, then you need

```
if (table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"] == null ||
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value.ToString() )
```

And since `table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value` may return null, then you need

```
if (table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"] == null ||
    table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value == null ||
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value.ToString() )
```

Comment: It's actually null sometimes, which is why im checking that

Comment: Lol this is much better than my solution. Write two ifs to check if the tables null so just so you can keep the `null OR Empty` construct. That's not hacky or completely stupid!